# get location of telegram robot owner

Tags: python, gps

In my script i want to get the location of telegram robot owner, when the users click on the button, the bot send the owner's location to the users as form as  google map image.
my script is:

```
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
import time
from gps3 import gps3

bot = telepot.Bot('mytoken')
def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    gps_socket = gps3.GPSDSocket()
    data_stream = gps3.DataStream()
    gps_socket.connect()
    gps_socket.watch()
    for new_data in gps_socket:
        if new_data:
            data_stream.unpack(new_data)
            alt = data_stream.TPV['alt']
            lat = data_stream.TPV['lat']
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id ,  alt)



MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
 while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

I run this script in my laptop and because my laptop hasn't gps i get error,When i run it with my android phone it should work but i get the same error

Comment: what do you mean by OWNER BOT ?

Comment: excuse me robot owner.

Comment: And how do you expect your android to run a python script?

Comment: I run this script in pycharm in my laptop, and run telegram in my android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this fully, but if lack of a GPS on the notebook is your only issue, what happens if you just replace a big chunk of your code like this while you are testing it? :

```
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
import time

bot = telepot.Bot('mytoken')
def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    lat = 53.540442
    long = 9.996381
    alt = 53.432        
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id ,  alt)

MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
 while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Just give it what it wants for coordinates and try to get the Telegram part of the script to work. Probably that `sendMessage` wants more than just altitude though..

Comment: I run this script in my notebook, it works and i didn't get any errors but it just send a number(alt = 53.432)and didn't send any location or google map image to telegram bot.

Comment: when i replace bot.sendmessage with bot.sendlocation(chat_id , lat,long,alt) it send a location to my bot.in my idea robot owner is variable and it isnt constant,so i can not use constant alt,long and lat numbers

Comment: The idea was just to help you remove the GPS issue while you were still testing on your PC so you could focus on the `telepot` part of it. If you want the owner variable, can't you just define `bot1=.. , bot2=..` at the top and several `MessageLoop` commands at the bottom (while testing.) If it was at all helpful don't forget to upvote.. Looking at [this](http://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#basic-bot) am not even sure you need `handle` in there.

Comment: yes thank you, i understand your mean.thank you for your reply, im trying to get latitude and longtitude in android and then define those to variable "lat" and "long" then i can send location with these parameter.of course you help me thank you very much

Comment: Good luck! Was going to say you would need languages other than Python to do this but found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917149/how-to-make-gps-app-for-android-using-kivy-pyjnius) here and [GitHub](https://github.com/kivy/plyer)