# How do I access the location of an iPhone with kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, kivy

I'm trying to access the location of my iPhone using kivy but haven't been able to figure it out. I've Googled it a bunch of times but it never worked. I got to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917149/how-to-make-gps-app-for-android-using-kivy-pyjnius), but pyjnius seems to be only for Android, not iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/kivy/plyer/ plyer supports gps location on both android (through pyjnius) and ios (through pyobjus), https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/examples/gps/main.py this basic example should give you a good start.

the important part is configuring the gps

```
            gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location,
                          on_status=self.on_status)
```

and later starting it with `gps.start()` and handling the coordinates in your `on_location` method.

```
    @mainthread
    def on_location(self, **kwargs):
        self.gps_location = '\n'.join([
            '{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])
```

Comment: Adding to Tshirtman's answer, you also need to add a field in your app's `your_app_name-Info.plist` file in Xcode. You need to add a key named `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description`, then give the value of that key a little message on why you need GPS access. The `.plist` file is under the *Resources* directory in your Xcode project.