# I want to implement GPS in my Kivy / Python application, but I don't know how to do it

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, gps

I have an application in Kivy / Python and now I need to implement a function that captures the last latitude and longitude of the phone and provides them for another function within the MainApp function, as I need this information in the form of a variable to do some calculations.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Window.clearcolor = [1, 1, 0.9, 0.9]

class MainApp(App):
    texture = ObjectProperty()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# >>>>>>>>> Here is the function that takes the latitude and longitude data from the GPS <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    def gps

# >>>>>>>>> And I need her to give me this data in 'lat'e' lon 'variables here inside a new function called calcu, so that I can do the calculations I want
    def calcu

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'MyApp'
        self.texture = Image(source = 'bgg.jpg').texture

    def calcular(self, *args):

        s_x = self.root.ids.x.text
        s_y = self.root.ids.y.text
        s_z = self.root.ids.z.text
        s_rpa = self.root.ids.rpa.text
        s_rt = self.root.ids.rt.text
        s_rpi = self.root.ids.rpi.text
        s_t = self.root.ids.t.text
        s_ii = self.root.ids.ii.text
        s_ie = self.root.ids.ie.text
        s_ac = self.root.ids.ac.text


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Condicionais e variáveis:

        if (s_x == ''):
            s_x = 6
        if (s_y == ''):
            s_y = 6
        if (s_z == ''):
            s_z = 3
        if (s_ie == ''):
            s_ie = 20000
        if (s_ii == ''):
            s_ii = 300
        if (s_t == ''):
            s_t = 0.88
        if (s_rpi == ''):
            s_rpi = 0.3
        if (s_rt == ''):
            s_rt = 0.7
        if (s_rpa == ''):
            s_rpa = 0.5
        if (s_ac == ''):
            s_ac = 90

        x = float(s_x)
        y = float(s_y)
        z = float(s_z)
        rpi = float(s_rpi)
        rt = float(s_rt)
        rpa = float(s_rpa)
        t = float(s_t)
        ac = float(s_ac)
        ii = float(s_ii)
        ie = float(s_ie)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Equacões:

        apa = 2*((x*z)+(y*z))
        api = x * y
        at = x * y
        a = apa + api + at
        r = ((rpa * apa) + (rpi * api) + (rt * at)) / a
        fld = (ii/ie)*100
        w = (fld*a*(1-(r ** 2))) / (t*ac)
        w = round(w, 3)
        w = str(w)
        w = w.replace(".", ",")
        w = w +" m²"

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Botão calcular:

        if (( t<=0 or t>1 ) or ( rpa<=0 or rpa>=1 ) or ( rpi<=0 or rpi >=1 ) or ( rt<=0 or rt>=1 ) or (ac<=0 or ac>180)):
            the_popup = Popup(title='Erro', content=Label(id='_result', text='Valor fornecido invalido.'),size_hint=(.5, .2), separator_color=[1, 1, 0.6, 0.8])
            the_popup.open()
        else:
            self.root.ids.resultado.text = w
            self.root.ids.resultado.opacity = 1

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def exit(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()

aplicativo = MainApp()
aplicativo.run()
```

And anticipating future questions, what configuration should I modify in buildozer.spec so that it allows the use of the phone's gps by the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make GPS-app for android using kivy, pyjnius?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16917149/295004)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make GPS-app for android using kivy, pyjnius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917149/how-to-make-gps-app-for-android-using-kivy-pyjnius)