# Android python environment with JDK

Tags: python, java, android

I'm working on a personal project of mine, and one of the requirements of that project is getting my android device's GPS location. I have tried many modules, but apparently it needs to be something integrated with Java Development Kit (JDK) because to access android's GPS module, you need to communicate with the device in Java. Here's what i tried, and results it yielded:

Here is my code in case it's of any relevance ...

```
from kivy import platform
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from geojson import Point

if platform == 'linux':
    from jnius import autoclass, cast

    # Import necessary Java classes
    LocationManager = autoclass('android.location.LocationManager')
    PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
    Looper = autoclass('android.os.Looper')
    Runnable = autoclass('java.lang.Runnable')

    # Define a Runnable to get the last known location
    class GetLastLocationRunnable(Runnable):
        def run(self):
            # Get the current activity
            activity = PythonActivity.mActivity

            # Get the location manager
            location_manager = activity.getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE)

            # Get the last known location
            last_known_location = location_manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

            # Call the on_location_received function on the main thread with the location
            mainthread.call_soon_threadsafe(on_location_received, last_known_location)

    # Callback function to process the received location
    def on_location_received(location):
        if location:
            latitude = location.getLatitude()
            longitude = location.getLongitude()
            
            # Create a GeoJSON Point object with the dynamic latitude and longitude
            point = Point((longitude, latitude))

            # Access the coordinates
            coordinates = point.coordinates

            print("Latitude:", coordinates[1])
            print("Longitude:", coordinates[0])
        else:
            print("No last known location available.")

    # Run the GetLastLocationRunnable on the main thread
    mainthread.call_soon(GetLastLocationRunnable().run)

else:
    print("GPS location retrieval is only supported on Android.")
```

At first I tried termux, but it quickly became apparent that this was not the right environment, as kivy (one of the very necessary modules) was impossible to install, and people online were saying that even if you do manage to install kivy on termux, it works all clanky and 1990's esque

Then I tried Pydroid 3, and that actually got me past python's ModuleNotFoundException as I was finally able to install all the necessary modules, however it always finished with an error, most recent one being `SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call` as a response to `from jnius import autoclass, cast` , and that according to chatGPT is an error resulting from the module not being able to find JDK ...

If you know any solutions to this problem without the need for change in environment, please let me know, i'm eager to try. Also if you know a python android environment that has JDK and works with jnius and kivy, let me know as well!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make GPS-app for android using kivy, pyjnius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917149/how-to-make-gps-app-for-android-using-kivy-pyjnius)